# Can't print out my array

Tags: java, arrays, system.out

```
public class LibraryMenu {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static Holding[]holding = new Holding[15];
static Member[]member = new Member[15];
static int hold = 0;
private static Scanner scanner;
public static void main(String[] args){
    int options;
    do{
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Library Management System");

        System.out.println("1. Add Holding");
        System.out.println("2. Print All Holding");

        options = scanner.nextInt();
        switch(options){

        case 1:
            addHolding();
            break;
        case 2:
            print();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please");
        }

    }while(options != 3);
    System.out.println("I'm out");

}
public static void addHolding(){
    int options1;
    do{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("1. Book");
    System.out.println("2. Video");
    System.out.println("3. Return");

    options1 = input.nextInt();

    switch(options1){

    case 1:
        addBook();
        break;

    case 2:
        addVideo();
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Please enter the following options");

    }

    }while(options1 != 3);

}

public static void addBook(){

    System.out.println("Title: " + "\t");
    String title = input.next();
    System.out.println("ID: " + "\t");
    String holdingId = input.next();   
    Book tempbook = new Book(title, holdingId);
    holding[hold] = tempbook;
    ++hold;


}

public static void addVideo(){
    System.out.println("Title: ");
    String title = input.next();
    System.out.println("ID: ");
    String holdingId = input.next();
    System.out.println("Loan Fee: ");
    int loanFee = input.nextInt();
    Video tempvideo = new Video(holdingId, title, loanFee);
    holding[hold] = tempvideo;
    ++hold;

}

public static void print(){

    for(int i = 0; i < holding.length; i++){
        System.out.println(holding[i]);


    }

}
}
```

When I use the print() method, nothing shows up. Wondering what is wrong with the code and why it is not printing out. Using user input to add books and video etc. Tried to look around the internet for this problem, but cant seem to find it.

Comment: Debugger is your friend ?

Comment: In the first line of the method "print()" add a line that says "System.out.println("printing");". In the console, does "printing" show up?

Comment: are you adding anything to your array first?  Is it sucessfully added?

Comment: BTW just use one Scanner object - also remember to consume any <ENTER> keys that you push

Comment: @Arman, yea it works, but it quickly disappears after